# unit test for a function that returns promise in angular service

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angularjs-service, angular-promise

I have a service that briefly looks like this:

```
function service($q) {

    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var templateService = {
       notifyChangeTemplate : notifyChangeTemplate 
    }
    return templateService;

    function notifyChangeTemplate(data) {

        deferred.notify(data);

        return deferred.promise;
    };
}
```

the function notifyChangeTemplate is called in two different controllers. one of them is notifying and the other one is using the returned promise.

I am trying to write unit test for this function tried this:

```
       it('should notify the promise', function () {
           var data = { test: 1 };

           var promise = myService.notifyChangeTemplate(data);

           promise.then(null, null, function (response) {

               var x = response;
               expect(x).toBe(data);

           });

           $scope.$apply();

       });
```

But it doesn't work and the "expect(x).toBe(data)" doesn't even get hit.

Can anyone give me some ideas how to test this function?